# CSS loader using translate3d doesn't work in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, loader

This CSS loader does not work in Internet Explorer 11, it only show the first keyframe and then nothing else happen.

```css
.loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -1em;
  margin-left: -1em;
  width: calc(2em + 1px);
  height: calc(2em + 1px);
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1em;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.loader div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background: orange;
  transform: translate3d(0em, 0em, 0) scale(0);
  animation: loaderStart 0.25s, loaderMove 1.5s 0.25s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.loader div:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0.65;
  animation: loaderStart 0.25s 0.5s, loaderMove 1.5s 0.75s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.loader div:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 0.35;
  animation: loaderStart 0.25s 0.5s, loaderMove 1.5s 1.25s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.nav__top .loader {
  position: relative;
  left: auto;
  top: auto;
  padding-top: 2em;
  margin-left: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
.konkurs-search__form-wrapper .loader {
  left: auto;
  margin-top: -0.2em;
  right: 20px;
}

@keyframes loaderStart {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes loaderMove {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0em, 0);
  }
  13% {
    transform: translate3d(0, calc(1em + 1px), 0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate3d(0, calc(1em + 1px), 0);
  }
  38% {
    transform: translate3d(calc(1em + 1px), calc(1em + 1px), 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate3d(calc(1em + 1px), calc(1em + 1px), 0);
  }
  63% {
    transform: translate3d(calc(1em + 1px), 0em, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate3d(calc(1em + 1px), 0em, 0);
  }
  88% {
    transform: translate3d(0em, 0em, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0em, 0em, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Can anybody see what the problem might be? I have an idea that it might be the translate3d, but not sure.
Looks like everything should be supported in Internet Explorer 11, if you look at caniuse.com, but something is obviously going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here problem is  **transform:translate3d(calc(1em + 1px)**  ,
I think calc method doesn't work inside translate or translate3d.

I made few changes and it seems to be working,

```
@keyframes loaderMove {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0em, 0);
  }
  13% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 17px, 0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 17px, 0);
  }
  38% {
    transform: translate3d(17px, 16px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate3d(17px, 17px, 0);
  }
  63% {
    transform: translate3d(17px, 0em, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate3d(17px, 0em, 0);
  }
  88% {
    transform: translate3d(0em, 0em, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0em, 0em, 0);
  }
}
```